# How to use Re.search to match either one of the keywords and find two words before and after?

Tags: python-re

Say that I have a comment from customer and I want to find out whether customer bought the gift for her: grandson, granddaughter, grand son, grand daughter, son, daughter, niece, nephew.
I can do one with the following code, but I'm not sure how to search all these key words in one re.search? Thanks.
re.search('(\w+\s+\w+)\s+grand daughter\s+(\w+\s+\w+)', review["Body"][iii])

Comment: Use re.findall?

Comment: It can be anywhere in string use this - `r"\b(?:grandson|granddaughter|grand son|grand daughter|son|daughter|niece|nephew)\b"`